# Is it recommended to make all classes inherit from a base class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm wondering whether should I make all my classes inherit from a base class, so as to be able to apply something like (garbage collection mechanism)

Comment: If you actually need shared ownership, look into shared_ptr, not inheritance.

Comment: It is certainly not conventional.

Comment: Don't do it without a strong design motivation, and even if you have it, consider alternative approaches because that would be a very invasive choice. I've seen it done a lot in GUI frameworks like VCL, Qt, ...

Comment: @MatG> you will see that a lot in frameworks and libs that were created in the 90s or early 2000s. Back then OO was the big thing (Java comes from that time too).

Comment: No. (This space intentionally left blank)

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not Java.

- You don't work with GC references, you work with actual objects.
- You don't allocate everything on the heap.
- You don't have complicated inheritance relationships if you don't need to.
- You don't make all methods virtual just in case they're overridden.
- The list goes on but I think you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to choose C++ over other languages is that it gives you fine-grained control over what your program does.  If you're willing to use garbage collection, it sounds like you're willing to give that up, at which point it probably makes a lot more sense to just write your program in something like C# anyway.  Which, by the way, will automatically make all your classes descend from a base class, namely `System.Object`.

(If you *are* wanting to do garbage collection but need to use C++ for some other reason, we probably need *far* more details about exactly what you're doing in order to advise you about the best approach.)